# Received an empty Json response using Python Requests

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests

On [zhihu](http://www.zhihu.com), a Chinese Q&A community similar to Quora,I am writing a small program to create a list of users who follow a particular user. On the page showing this information, by scrolling down to the bottom, the browser sends a post request and receives a response in json to extend the followers list.

A snippet of the received json is (copied from firebug):

```
{"r":0,"msg":["<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"f09ebe71535bd89a43dd979c77cf3676\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-unfollow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u53d6\u6d88\u5173\u6ce8<\/button>.....
```

I have little knowledge about json but I am sure that 'msg' contains information about followers.

In my program, I use Python [Requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to send this post request to server.

```
payload={"method":"next","params":params,"_xsrf":_xsrf}#form data 
response=session.post('http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2',data=payload,headers=header)
```

response has a status code 200, but response.json() returns:

```
{u'msg': [], u'r': 0}
```

where the 'msg' is empty. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You're sure it's POST and not GET that the browser is doing?

Comment: Looks like you should be registered and logged in to view someone's followers. Right?

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am sure it's POST request as I saw it in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this very problem when I tried to get the content in the returned json file. To solve this, you just need to adjust one thing.

```
payload={"method":"next","params":params,"_xsrf":_xsrf}
```

Notice the params. You didn't show us what exactly it was. Since you and I have the same question, I'd assume that your params looks like this,

```
params = json.dumps({"offset":20,"order_by":"created","hash_id":"blablabla"})
```

Here is the big one. Your value of "offset" must be an integer, 20 in this case, but definitely not a string, say something like "20". It's really hard to tell what goes wrong when every element is double quoted.

**Remember,the value of "offset" must be an integer!**

```
"offset":20
```